# Installing jalopy to RAD eclipse

Tags: java, ibm-rad, jalopy

I use RAD Eclipse as my IDE and I am trying to install jalopy into my IDE.

I googled how to install jalopy into eclipse but there was no clear way in how to do it. One site says to install the `jalopy-setup-1.9.4_118.jar`. however, it doesn't provide where I can get that jar.

My question is, how do I install jalopy into my RAD eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

This is so old that I would't advise to use it. Even I'm not sure it works on latest RAD/Eclipse because the last version is from 2004.

Anyway, if at any chance is possible, you need to download the Eclipse package and uncompress it onto the dropins folder in RAD

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/jalopy/jalopy-eclipse-0.2.7.zip

However, like I said, I can't promise it will work.

I'd like to recommend you other tools. For instance, in RAD you get tools for static analysis. You can configure the rules there to match your own set, pretty much like Jalopy used to do (at least that's what I understand by reading the sourceforge site).